# Where do Magento2 Questions Belong?

Tags: discussion, magento2

I certainly don't think inquiries about Magento 2 belong in the magento.stackexchange; can we hurry up and confirm/enforce this? I feel all inquiries should be directed at the brand and/or the repository.

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: Just seems kind of crazy to dilute the SE before a production ready stable release is out, esp. when there is a repository which users can create issues on.

Answer (score 6):

Magento 2 questions are allowed.
They should just be tagged with the proper version to make a difference between pre-alpha, alpha, beta, rc and official release.

Answer (score 3):

I think some question which fit squarely into the "issues" bucket *belong* on GitHub. But for questions which do not rise to the level of "hey something's broken" or "hey I have an architectural suggestion / improvement" are noise in a GitHub context. My opinion of course, and curious to hear the opinions of others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two cents. Magento 2 is the newest edition of Magento. If a question clearly states it is related to Magento 2 I see absolutely no reason why it does not belong on magento.stackexchange.com.